# Calculating conditional probability using VineCopula in R

Tags: r, conditional-probability, copula, vine-copula

I have a dataframe X (with columns `x1` and `x2`) and would like to calculate conditional probability, something like P(x1<0.5|x2<0.3), which can be calculated using `BiCopCDF`. My question is: how do I obtain the transformed values (i.e., `u` and `v`) from the original data (`x1` and `x2`)?

How can I obtain the `u` and `v` values corresponding to `x1=0.5` and `x2=0.3`, to further explain it using the aforementioned example. One option is to find a distribution that fits `x1` and `x2` the best and then calculate CDF, however, I am not sure how well any particular distribution would fit the data. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code I am using:

```r
u <- pobs(X)[,1]
v <- pobs(X)[,2]

par_clay = BiCopEst(u,v,3)$par
cop_clay = BiCop(family = 3, par = par_clay) #family 3 for clayton copula

copula_cdf = BiCopCDF(u = u1, v = v1, cop_clay)
conditional_cdf = copula_cdf/ecdf(v1)
```

Comment: This seems to concern how this particular software works.  In particular, what would the argument `family = 3` mean?

Comment: Oh, it is the family no for clayton copula.

Comment: Okay.  How, then, does your software estimate the transformation?  One would guess it is applying some version of an empirical (marginal) distribution.  What does its documentation say?

Comment: I checked it uses empirical distribution

Comment: Good!  That's your answer.

Comment: @whuber to clarify, do you suggest calculating empirical CDF of x1 and x2, then interpolate the values on x1 = 0.5 and x2 = 0.3, because what if there is no [0.5, 0.3] in the original data?

Comment: It depends on how the software computes the ECDF.  If it does not interpolate, then you probably shouldn't, either.

Comment: Your provided codes answer your question.

Comment: @Dr.Alenezi I edited the code, it now has the conditional cdf calculation. The problem is x2 is always >1 in the original data; this makes the ecdf_x2(0.3) = 0 and the conditional CDF undefined. Is there a way to generate random samples of x1 and x2 which are not uniformly distributed but have the same marginal distribution as x1 and x2.

Comment: This sounds like a feature, not a problem!  How can you hope to know anything about the conditional distribution of a value that is beyond the range of what you observed, unless you somehow explicitly extrapolate?  And how would you do that?

Comment: @whuber Your comment makes sense, however, I was hoping to generate some random numbers (around 10000) and have some values of x2<1. Though I am not sure if that's the correct approach.

Comment: You have not specified any model for either marginal. Instead, you've estimated the copula parameters from pseudo-observations. So, you don't actually have a joint model, and if you want to compute conditional probabilities, you're going to have to make some choices first so you can complete the specification of your model.

Comment: @ChrisHaug do I first need to get the marginal distributions and generate random variables for x1 and x2 and then specify copula? Am I doing wrong by fitting the copula to pseudo-observations? What choices do I need to make for calculating conditional probabilities?